# Jquery ui autocomplete incorrectly detects change on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, reload

I have a set of fields that are autocomplete fields.  Each one is set up to detect when a change is made and if the final value does not match any suggestions, it puts the field in an error state and asks the user to select an existing item.  Here is the code:

```
$.each($(".autocomplete"), function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).attr("autocomplete-url"),
            autoFocus: true,   //Just press enter to select top item
            minLength: 0,
            response: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.content.length == 1) {
                    $(this).val(ui.content[0].value);
                    $(this).removeClass("is-invalid").next("span").remove(); //valid value, remove error
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {  //if detects a string that was not suggested (meaning does not exist in DB), clear value and show not valid
                if (!(ui.item)) {      //don't close the dropdown - causes ui.item to be undefined
                    $(this).val("");
                    $(this).addClass("is-invalid").after("<span class='invalid-feedback'><strong>Please choose an existing " + $(this).attr('name') + ".</strong></span>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This works fine except in one case - if there is an error elsewhere in the form and the page reloads with the other form errors (No error in the autocomplete field), the originally selected item in the autocomplete shows for a split second, then the change event runs removing the value and putting the field in a state of error with the message "Please choose an existing item."

Is there a way to tell the autocomplete that the value it contains on page reload is in fact valid and has not changed - it's the same value that was valid before page reload?  Or, does anyone have another suggestion like maybe suppressing the autocomplete change even when the page reloads and then enabling it again in case the user selects another item?

Comment: Won't page refresh reinitialize auto-complete?

Comment: Yes, it should re-initialize on page reload.  I am using the Django framework for the back end.  If there is an error in a form, the page reloads with all the form data the same and displaying errors on fields that have not validated. I guess the question here is how would I modify the autocomplete init to run a search from the source on page reload to determine if the value placed there is valid.  Right now, it seems to only run the change event on page load when the value from the form is placed there.

Comment: Yes, you can set the Value of the field upon Create or before. The issue is how do you retain the value before reload?

Comment: @Mostafa you can remove change from initilizee and delegate it later when DOM is loaded